# Loading an assembly at runtime in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, .net-assembly

I've got a little problem with my Xamarin.Forms Application.
I'll try to implement an on the fly updater, which downloads some DLLs from a Webservice an loads it.
It works fine with the Shared piece of code., but when it comes to a dll which contains Android specific stuff then it does not work perfectly.

For example: I have to register Dependency manually in a method which I call when the DLL get loaded.
Sadly it doesn't work with CostumRenderer. Xamarin just doesn't recognize that I want to register an Costumrenderer... Do anyone have an idea how to fix this Problem or does someone got a smart workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serve me right. I think Apple specifically prevent dynamic code loading due to security concern. So i think even if you're able to do that in test you will get reject by Apple

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i tested it and for me it seems to be working. It loads the dll in a simulator and runs it